# Como posso transformar uma string de números em uma matrix?

Tags: javascript, matriz

Estou fazendo um exercício onde devo extrair linhas e colunas de uma string, criando uma matriz.

Dado um input  `let str = '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9'`, eu escrevi um código que retorna: `[ '4 5 6' ]`, porém gostaria que ele retornasse algo do tipo: `[4, 5, 6]` (sem estar entre as aspas). Como posso fazer isso?

```
let str = '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9'
let arr = str.split('\n');
    let rowResult = [];
    let rowFinalResult = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        rowResult = arr[i];
        rowFinalResult.push([rowResult]);
    }
    console.log(rowFinalResult[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o `str.split('\n')`, você está dividindo a string original um *array* com três outras strings, separadas pelo `'\n'`.

No entanto, para cada uma dessas três novas strings, você deve separá-las novamente, de modo a "individualizar" cada string numérica (separando pelo espaço `' '`). Veja:

```js
let str = '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9';

let arr = str.split('\n');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].split(' ');
}

console.log(arr);
```

Para transformar cada string em número, podemos utilizar o `map`. Note, no código acima, que a expressão `arr[i].split(' ')` retorna um *array*. Assim, utilizando o [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), podemos mapear cada elemento em um número (convertendo-os utilizando o [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).

```js
let str = '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9';

let arr = str.split('\n');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i]
    .split(' ')
    .map((str) => parseInt(str, 10));
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Achei muito boa sua resposta, simples, prática e bem explicada. Obrigado! Resolveu meu problema

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso, o que você precisaria fazer é o seguinte, quando você recebe o "rowResult", você recebe uma string onde os números são separados por espaços. Se você substituir o espaço por vírgula, vai chegar no resultado desejado, isso pode ser feito utilizado o método "replaceAll". Seu código ficaria assim:

```
let str = '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9'
let arr = str.split('\n');
let rowResult = [];
let rowFinalResult = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    rowResult = arr[i];
    rowFinalResult.push(rowResult.replaceAll(' ',','));
}
console.log(rowFinalResult[1]);
```

Comment: Havia pensado em algo do tipo também, porém sem usar o replaceAll. Quando testei o código, foi retornado o erro de que o rowResult.replaceAll não é uma função, o que poderia ter ocorrido? Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @ju4ncrls, o `replaceAll` provavelmente não funcionou porque o seu ambiente de execução ainda não o suporta. Conforme você pode verificar [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#Browser_compatibility), o suporte ainda não é dos melhores porque essa edição do ECMAScript ainda nem foi liberada (ECMAScript 2021). Para testar se o seu ambiente o suporta, basta utilizar a expressão: `typeof String.prototype.replaceAll`. Se retornar `undefined`, você não poderá o utilizar.